# Css not loading in the other folders- PHP- GCP

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, yaml, app.yaml

I've deployed a website on GCP. The homepage is loading with CSS and other static files, But in the inside folders css is not loading(Attached images[homepage- index.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGGl4.jpg) [user/index.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GH7S.png)) . Here's my app.yaml code

```
# Use the PHP 7.3 runtime (BETA) by replacing "php/2" below with "php73"
runtime: php74

# Defaults to "arve-intes pļ" und "serve public/index.php". Can be used to 
# serve a custom PHP front controller (e.g. "serve backend/Index.php") or to s run a long-running PHP script as a worker process (e.g. "php worker.php"). 
#
# Serve your app through a front controller at index.php or public/index.php.

runtime_config: 
  document_root: .


handlers:
- url: /css
  static_dir: css
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301

# Serve images as static resources.
- url: /(.+\.(gif|png|jpg|css|js|map|PNG))$
  static_files: \1
  upload: .+\.(gif|png|jpg|css|js|map|PNG)$

- url: /.*
  script: auto
  secure: always


entrypoint:
  serve handler.php


env_variables:
#Replace USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE, and CONNECTION NAME with the
#values obtained when configuring your Cloud SQL instance:
  CLOUDSQL_USER: root
  CLOUDSQL_DB: dbs5349083
  CLOUDSQL_PASSMORD: Test@123 
  CLOUDSQL_DSN: /cloudsql/tactile-timer-340721:us-east1:mysql

# [END gae cloudsql_mysql_eny)
```

Comment: Did you figure out what was the issue? I am having the same problem

Comment: I guess we were able to load css for some pages, but in the end we have to abandon the project for some other reasons. Also I left company and I dont have the full code now, dont remember aswell